# How to set default json serialization settings for HttpClient (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a WinForms app that uses a Web API back-end and I want all the HTTP requests / responses to use specific json SerializerSettings.  On the server-side, this is easy by just doing this in Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

On the client-side, I tried this:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
}.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

This works when I use JsonConvert explicitly, e.g.:

```
var someVm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeVm>(jsonString);
```

However, it does not take effect for calls using HttpClient.GetAsync / PostAsAsync, etc.  resulting in an exception:

> Error converting value 2/24/2018 4:00:00 PM to type
>   'System.Nullable`1[NodaTime.LocalDateTime]'. Path
>   'folderExpectedDate', line 16, position 45.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   2/24/2018 4:00:00 PM to type
>   'System.Nullable`1[NodaTime.LocalDateTime]'. Path
>   'folderExpectedDate', line 16, position 45. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from
>   System.DateTime to NodaTime.LocalDateTime.

Note, the exact same JSON that causes the exception above works fine when calling DeserializeObject as above.

**How can I set / modify the default serialization settings used by HttpClient** (I do not want to specify it in every call - there are several hundreds of them)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with that seems to work well so far (for my purposes) and is pretty clean.

For reading Json response from server (based on: http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/10/httpcontent-readasasync-with-net-core-2/):

```
public static class HttpContentExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpContent content, JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = null)
    {
        if (jsonSerializerSettings == null)
        {
            jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
            }.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        }

        string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        T value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var someVm = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<SomeVm>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For Puts, Posts, etc.:

```
//var response = await WebServiceUtil.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("designSalesJob/new", designSalesJob).ConfigureAwait(false);
var response = await WebServiceUtil.HttpClient.PostAsync("designSalesJob/new", designSalesJob, HttpUtil.JsonFormatter).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here is the JsonFormatter utility method (will refactor the ReadAsJsonAsync above to also use this):

```
public static class HttpUtil
{
    public static JsonMediaTypeFormatter JsonFormatter => new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
        }.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb)
    };
}
```

Feedback on this solution is of course welcome...

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContent` extension methods are defined in [`HttpContentExtensions`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentExtensions.cs) and they use a private static [`MediaTypeFormatterCollection`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/MediaTypeFormatterCollection.cs) containing `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`, `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` and `new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter`.

Those extension methods, allow you to pass a custom list of `MediaTypeFormatter`. They use formatters which you pass or if you don't pass any formatter they will use the private static formatters collection. So as a conclusion:

- You can create a static list of formatters and setup them and pass it to methods every time you want to call methods.
- You have the option of setting up the static formatter collection of `HttpContentExtensions` class using reflection. Then the setting will be always used by those extension methods.

**Example**

You can create a class which expose the static private `DefaultMediaTypeFormatterCollection` property of `HttpContextException`:

```
public class HttpClientDefaults
{
    public static MediaTypeFormatterCollection MediaTypeFormatters
    {
        get
        {
            var p = typeof(HttpContentExtensions).
                GetProperty("DefaultMediaTypeFormatterCollection",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
            return (MediaTypeFormatterCollection)p.GetValue(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in startup of your application, you can setup formatters in a single point:

```
var jsonFormatter = HttpClientDefaults.MediaTypeFormatters
    .OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();

// Setup jsonFormatter, for example using jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
```

The setting will be used for all extension methods to deserialize from json and you don't need to change the way that you call those methods:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:58045/api/products/1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
}
```

Comment: Surely with the idea which is shared in this post, you can create your custom extension methods which use your custom formatter/settings.

Comment: man, how come `HttpClient` does not allow to configure this globally, right? For `Content.ReadAsAsync` it is "easy" to pass the json converters, but for `client.PostAsJson` there is no way... setting via reflection will work for `client.PostAsJson`?