# Setting defaults for JsonContent in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, configuration, system.text.json

I'm trying to send a POST request with multipart form data (a file and a Json field) in Asp.Net Core 6.0. The relevant part of the code is

```
...

using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myrequest");
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    {new StreamContent(image), "data", "file.ext"},
    {JsonContent.Create(myObject), "Object"}
};
request.Content = content;
using var res = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

...
```

This works, except that the company policy is to serialize Json fields in PascalCase, whereas `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web`, which is used by `JsonContent`, defaults to camelCase.

I can fix this specific instance by writing

```
{JsonContent.Create(myObject, null, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = null }), "Object"}
```

but the problem then becomes that I have to do this anywhere where I build such a request.

**My question: can I set PascalCase for `JsonContent` globally somewhere?**

I can set this for the controllers via `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);`,
and there are questions such as [How to set default json serialization settings for HttpClient (WinForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998670/how-to-set-default-json-serialization-settings-for-httpclient-winforms) , but none of them seem to apply to `JsonContent` in Asp.Net Core with `System.Text.Json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no option for telling `JsonContent.Create()` to use the global *JsonSerializerOptions*.

**BUT** you could use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-interfaces) to retrieve the global JsonSerializerOptions, you've added with `AddJsonOptions(...);`.

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

**Options injected in Controller:**

```
private readonly IOptions<JsonOptions> _JsonOptions;

public YourController(IOptions<JsonOptions> options)
{
    _JsonOptions = options;
}

...

// in your request method:
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myrequest");
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StreamContent(image), "data", "file.ext" },
    { JsonContent.Create(wfc, null, JsonOptions.Value.JsonSerializerOptions), "Object" }
};
request.Content = content;
using var res = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

...
```

To simplify things a bit more, you could use a static helper method, so you don't need to pass the type and you can just pass the options.

**PascalCaseHelper.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class PascalCaseHelper
    {
        public static StringContent CreateJson(object data, IOptions<JsonOptions> options)
        {
            return new StringContent(
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options.Value.JsonSerializerOptions), 
                Encoding.UTF8,
                MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
        }
    }
}


// Usage:
{ PascalCaseHelper.CreateJson(myObject, _JsonOptions), "Object" }
```

Comment: Obviously not what I was hoping for, but appears to be the correct answer. I ended up using DI to pass an options object, although the options pattern you suggest might be even better. As there are no other answers, I'll accept this one.